# Query Azure table storage in an azure function and insert into Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have an azure function and I want to grab the data from an Azure table and then push it to CRM. The creating of records in CRM is the easy part, but I am not sure how to access the table correctly.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, Lead lead, TraceWriter log)
{
    var connectionString = "AuthType=Office365;Username=*****; Password=****;Url=*****";
CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
using (OrganizationService orgService = new OrganizationService(connection))
{
try
{
    var query = new QueryExpression("account");
    query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("name");
    var ec = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    log.Verbose(ec[0].GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
    Lead lead = new Lead();
    string name = lead.LeadSource;
    Console.WriteLine("name is: {0}", name);
    //log.Verbose($"Name in Person entity: {lead.Name}");
}
    catch (ArgumentNullException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", e);
    }
  }
}


public class Lead 
{
public string PartitionKey {get; set;}
public string RowKey { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ProductId {get; set;}
public string CustomerInfo {get; set;}
public string LeadSource {get; set;}
public string ActionCode {get; set;}
public string PublisherDisplayName {get; set;}
public string OfferDisplayName {get; set;}
public string CreatedTime {get; set;}
public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

In the lines:

```
Lead lead = new Lead();
string name = lead.LeadSource;
Console.WriteLine("name is: {0}", name);
```

I want the specified value for leadsource to be printed from the dataset but it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving data from an Azure table requires the [Azure Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-tools?view=azure-dotnet&tabs=windows), or at least the [Storage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), and a few commands, as taken from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition):

```
// Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Construct the query operation for all customer entities where PartitionKey="Smith".
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"));

// Print the fields for each customer.
foreach (CustomerEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
        entity.Email, entity.PhoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: I've read you should use a Singleton when querying CosmosDB from an Azure function. Do you need to do that with CloudTableClient ?